# How to make this code more efficient so a large number of if statements isn't required?

Tags: python

I'm making a bit of code for proof of concept in python, all it is is when the user inputs !reply before their message it prints it without the "!reply" at the front. I have got it to work although I feel like I have done it in a very inefficient way, how could I improve this?

```
message = input("Message: ").lower()
message_list = []
new_message = ""
count = 0

for letter in message:
    message_list.append(letter)
print(message_list)
if message_list[0] == "!":
    if message_list[1] == "r":
        if message_list[2] == "e":
            if message_list[3] == "p":
                if message_list[4] == "l":
                    if message_list[5] == "y":
                        if message_list[6] == " ":
                            for alpha in message_list[7:]:
                                new_message = new_message + alpha
print(new_message)
```

Comment: well.. you seem to know what a loop is because you have one in the code ahead of this... staircase.. you've constructed... simple string matching maybe.. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write all of your `if` statements in one:

```
if message_list[:7] == list("!reply "):
```

This will compare each element of `message_list` (up to the 7th element) to the corresponding index in `list("!reply ")`, which is equivalent to:

```
["!", "r", "e", "p", "l", "y", " "]
```

i.e., the string is converted to a list of characters.

Another, more pythonic, way to achieve this would be to test if the message [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) `"!reply"`:

```
if message.startswith("!reply "):
    new_message = message[7:]
    print(new_message)
```

Answer (score 1):

A correct solution for this case was shown, but in general:

```
if cond1:
  if cond2:
    if cond3:
       ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
if cond1 and cond2 and cond3 ....:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the string as a list a of characters as is. No need to parse it into a list:

```
message = input("Message: ").lower()

if message.startswith('!reply '):
    print(message[7:])
```